# Design Pattern to determine necessary variable type

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns

I'm hoping to get some advice on a design pattern or strategy for the following situation:

I have a controller class which, given a queue of media, should present an appropriate player. The media may be video, audio, or other. Each media type has a corresponding player type, and each player implements a common protocol which defines methods for play, pause, stop, etc. The controller class needs to keep a reference to the current player, though that player may be one of several types. One thought is to keep a reference using the id type:

```
@property id currentPlayer;
```

Alternatively, I can create a superclass Player and have each player type subclass Player:

```
@interface VideoPlayer : Player
```

Then in the controller class, I can keep a reference to the Player class and cast it to the specific type when needed:

```
@property Player *currentPlayer;
```

Both options seem wrong to me, so I wonder if there is a design pattern or otherwise better strategy that might help me implement this. Any examples in Cocoa or Objective-C would be especially helpful - thanks.

Comment: Do you ever need to invoke methods on the player that are not in the common protocol?  Your superclass idea is fine.  Declare that superclass as conforming to the common protocol and (if you're only invoking that protocol) then you won't even need the cast.

Comment: After a bit more research, I believe the design pattern I was looking for is the Abstract factory pattern (expressed in Objective-C as class clusters).

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use
`id<YourProtocol> currentPlayer;`
?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type `id<MyProtocol> currentPlayer;`

To determine the actual class of player you can use `[currentPlayer isKindOfClass:[MyPlayerType class]]`